# C# Interop, how to get the max length within a range of cells in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I would like to get the max length within a range of cells in Excel using C# interop library.

I know that we can do it via in excel:-

```
1. =MAX(LEN(A2:A65636))

2. press ctrl+shft+enter after typing in the formula.
```

But I would like to do it using formula by my C# program.

Currently I am looping through all the cells within the column range and setting the maximum count. But it is taking lot of time for big excel file aroung 50000 rows.

I have tried even, setting the formula dynamically `=MAX(LEN(A2:A rcnt))`

But that doesn't work.

Comment: It is slow because of the process interop.  Keep the formula, but loop on Application.CalculationState so you can be sure that Excel has calculated the value.

Comment: Is this poosible to do something like below, currently it is not working for me
 1. Input the formula
 2. SendKeys Shift+Ctrl+Enter to the xlApp

new_formula = "=MAX(LEN(F2:F56))";

(range.Cells[1, cl + 1] as Excel.Range).Value2 = new_formula 

xlApp.SendKeys("+^{ENTER}");

Please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the range.FormulaArray property to set formulas to a cell using C#.

For example:

```
Range r = activeWorksheet.get_Range("Y9",Type.Missing);
r.FormulaArray = "=MAX(LEN(D3:E3))";
```